# New Spring Boot Project Build Failure in Intellij

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have created a new spring boot project using https://start.spring.io/

While trying to import it in Intellij, the build is failing with the message

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.util.ModuleComponentIdentifierImpl.getModuleIdentifier()Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleIdentifier;
```

Java version: 8
Gradle version: 5.6

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after reproducing the issue?

Comment: It seems to be the issue with Intellij Gradle plugin. I was using IntelliJ 2018 version, after upgrading it to 2019.2 issue got resolved.
Thanks

Comment: Consider adding your comment as answer and marking it as resolved

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the issue with Intellij Gradle plugin. I was using IntelliJ 2018 version, after upgrading it to 2019.2 issue got resolved